# Error using GRASS in QGIS 3.22: can't open file 'C:\etc\grass78.py'

Tags: qgis

I have the last version of QGIS installed through advanced installation (OSGeo4W). However I cannot use the GRASS algorithms due to this error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
C:\OSGeo4W\bin\python3.exe: can't open file 'C:\etc\grass78.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Can anyone help me, please?
In the following image there are the versions installed in my computer.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 versions of QGis: 3.22 and 3.16.

You can try to reinstall QGis and Grass with the osgeo4w installer by choosing normal mode (not advanced)